# Replace letters with numbers in a string

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to replace letters in my string to numbers that I have stored on an object. This is my current function but I can't make it to work.

```
letters = {
a: 4,
e: 3,
i: 1,
o: 0,
s: 5
};

function leetSpeaker(str) {
for (var i= 0; i < str.length; i++) {
if (letters[str[i]]) {
    str = str.replace(str[i], letters[str[i]]);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: did you mean for your if to be `if( letters.hasOwnProperty( str[i] ) )`, which would check if the letter from `str` is set in your object

Comment: @PatrickEvans right.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/55n8ahsc/ - what is it doing incorrectly?

Comment: Your solution does seem to work, you have to return the string after replacing with numbers. https://jsbin.com/siyukuq/edit?js,console

Comment: @BarbaraLaird wow, I wasn't returning. Thank You!